# Which Supervised ML technique to use?

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning

I am working on a project where I have to classify whether the condition is critical or not. My readings are energy meter readings whose values keep changing every min. Also, I do not have a specific value which can tell that beyond this, a condition is critical. My confusion is which Supervised technique is suitable in this case and why?? Kindly help as I am new to ML I cannot come to a conclusive point.

Comment: You should first define what your problem is.  What are your inputs?  Are they the energy meter readings?  What is your output?  That is, what would machine learning be predicting here?

Comment: I want ML to predict whether the readings currently shown by the meter are depicting a critical stage or not. My input is meter readings like current. And for that, I want the suggestion of which ML technique can be used for classification?